# How to extract SOAP Header from WS Response

Tags: java, c#, web-services, wcf, soap

I am in .NET environment and calling a Java SOAP Webservice. I added the Service as a **Web Reference** and it loaded Proxy and config settings for me. So far so good.

Now, to me it is just like calling another library because all the types are loaded and I can call methods and assign the return types to the Proxy classes that .Net generated for me.

However, my provider says that they are sending some **cookies in the SOAP Header**. Now, how do I access SOAP header from my C# code?Because when I call the service and retrieve the response, it is like calling a method and retrieving a Typed response. Not sure how to extract SOAP header information from it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **OperationContext** class: https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.servicemodel.operationcontext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

> Use the OperationContext from within a service operation to access the
>   current operation execution environment. In particular, the operation
>   context is used to access callback channels in duplex services, to
>   store extra state data across portions of the operations, and to
>   access incoming message **headers** and properties as well as add outgoing
>   message headers and properties.

You can read information from Header like this (replace "Cookie" with the tag name that you want to read):

```
var cookieIndex = OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageHeaders.FindHeader("Cookie", "");
XmlReader reader = OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageHeaders.GetReaderAtHeader(cookieIndex).ReadSubtree();
```

Hope it helps

Comment: My OperationContext.Current is Null. Wouldn't this be the case if I am on the Client side. It says that you will have a context if you are on the server and the client calls you ?

Comment: On the client, you must [create an `OperationContextScope` around the service call](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.operationcontextscope(v=vs.110).aspx), best done with the `using` statement.

Comment: AS @PauloMadeira noticed, you need a scope of OperationContext. It depends on how you create your client. This post has good information about: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15205337/current-operationcontext-is-null-in-wcf-windows-service